# How can i know supported intents of the 3rd party app

Tags: android, android-intent

I've built an app called xLancer (https://market.android.com/details?id=kz.jay.xlancer.activity) that retrieves job listings from Elance. Now i want to implement a feature that would remind me to bid on a project at a later time. Instead of reinventing the wheel i want to launch any external TODO/Task manager app. But now i am stuck, i don't know which URI or action should be specified, so far i've only used intents to call my internal activities by specifying class name explicitly.

So the question is: how can i know which URI/action should be specified?

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable), I didn't see any Todo/Task intents there though....

Comment: I've seen it before. So it seems like there is no magic way to retrieve supported intents. And the manifest file is in binary format...